# How to create type/interface from another type interface?

Tags: typescript

I have interface of values types:

```
interface ValuesTypes {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
```

and Union of Controls:

```
type Controls = 'selectFoo' | 'tbxBar';
```

and map controls to values names:

```
const mapControlsToValues: Record<Controls, keyof ValuesTypes> = {
  selectFoo: 'foo',
  tbxBar: 'bar',
};
```

How can I get the ElementsTypes interface using code described above?

```
interface ElementsTypes {
  selectFoo: string;
  tbxBar: number;
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIGcAqAngA57IDeAUMsjAPZ0BcyuYUoA5gNzXIBGcKMxBYAtn2g8AvpUpgSKAMJ1wUOhlzIAvMgDkuCBggIwAMQa7kAHz1g+ADwBCg3T0oIVrZKLjFlq9QI6dGwyHSoaAyMTcyY9ejpdABpeOydBZl0BKGTKKWQ4TQ8QVjd5UmQAUXwAHnwk5ABpAD5tCl4AWigIOAATFQxCZABtRogh0GQAa3G6GGR8AF1mfFHxxeQIe0gQXs1QGGhkAGVeGgB+E83tiF3NGcI5puQzmmRLxuHjjdeaYQgAG5HV7-IFQPKycooSpGUS3MAEBSaHTVGpQp4+PwqNiBfDBTA4XANEKEoikXDNSgAeipbwAeucgA) work for you?

Comment: @tobias-s

awesome! that's what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you defined `mapControlsToValues` doesn't really work, because you are defining each value as a `keyof ValuesTypes`, meaning, that each value can actually be `foo` or `bar`, and not the type that you passed in.

So, my advice is that you should rely on TypeScript's inference to do the job! In order to do that, you must **create a generic function** and use the "literal" type that you passed in. This way you will still have the same type safety, and be able to have concrete typing for your `mapControlsToValues` object.

1- Create a generic function

```
function getControlValues<T extends Record<Controls, keyof ValuesTypes>>(arg: T){
  return arg;
}
```

2- Extract the type of the generated type

```
const mapControlsToValues = getControlValues({
  selectFoo: 'foo',
  tbxBar: 'bar',
})

type ControlValuesType = typeof mapControlsToValues;
```

3- Create a new object type based on your `ControlValuesType`

```
type ElementsTypes = {
  [Key in keyof ControlValuesType]: ValuesTypes[ControlValuesType[Key]];
};
```

And that's it, you have defined a type that follows the ElementsTypes interface. If you really need it to be an interface you can always extend the created type like so:

```
interface MyInterface extends ElementsTypes {}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIGcAqAngA57IDeAUMsjAPZ0BcyuYUoA5gNzXIBGcKMxBYAtn2g8AvpUpgSKAMJ1wUOhlzIAvMgBEuCBggIwAMQa7kAHz1g+ADwBCg3T0owsIE8BXIOEMGVVdXRsPAAefGQIe0gQABNNACVjOih48KC2dVwAGmQAawhCOhg0TBwCBVwAPhqACl5BDmZ8SgBKCl4oAKwoEGRm6VkEFVZkUThiLLUNfDpQyu0-AJmQirx6qhoDIxNzJj16Ol1c3jsnQWZdAShTyil2t3lSZDWMRbwiV50XiFKJlN3gQFhtcM8FMgAKJGUQQcBVUiaHTbZAAbQA0sVkKBCsUAe9PoiIABdZhE754NGEsGUzHFEkk6RcIA)